# Question about w3w dictionary exercise questions for python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a really basic question for dictionaries from one of the exercises. The question is :
Write a Python script to generate and print a dictionary that contains a number (between 1 and n) in the form (x, x*x).

This here is my code:

```
import random
def dict_generate():
    n = int(input("Please enter an integer:"))
    dic = {}
    for x in range(n):
        num = random.randrange(1,n)
        key = num
        value = num*num
        dic[key] = value
    
    print(dic)

dict_generate()
```

However, when I run it, it seems to skip over a few iterations, so the end result is that I get a dictionary with lesser values in it that the number I entered. For example, I entered 5, but instead of 5 sets of keys and values, my output was this:
**{3: 9, 1: 1, 2: 4}**

Running this code through python tutor, the problem seems to be that the values are not being inserted into the dictionary. I can't seem to understand why. If someone could explain it would be really helpful thanks.
(I am aware that there are many other ways to complete this question but I'm trying to understand where I went wrong.)

Comment: Why did you use `num = random.randrange(1,n)`?

Comment: If you use random numbers, that will probably happen...

Comment: Yeah, it's most likely that some of the keys were the same, thus modifying the same item in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
 num = random.randrange(1,n)
 key = num
```

Since you use the key as a random number it may come again and again the same number for the key so your dictionary has less than 5 keys.

[image]